# How to share a google spreadsheet that contains google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I followed [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bracket_maker) at google developer web site to create a spreadsheet. And as expected when I reloaded the spreadsheet, a menu called "Bracket Maker" is now available on the menu bar.

But if I share this document to my friends, they can open this document, see all the content in the document. But they just don't have the "Bracket Maker" menu bar. How should I do to make sure they also get the script capability?

Comment: Custom menus will appear only if your friend has editor or owner access in the spreadsheet. Viewer and Commenter access will not show custom menu

Comment: Right, by giving my friend editor access then the menu bar appears.

Answer (score 0):

The menu is created when the onOpen is triggered. 
How are you creating the menu - using the onOpen function or an installed trigger ?

If you created it using an installable trigger, then your friends have to set up the trigger manually.

Comment: The tutorial is using onOpen.